# carddav and caldav configuration with sogo using php in web app

Tags: php, gmail-imap, carddav, sabredav

I'm newbie in cardav and caldav protocol. I have do lot of search in regarding this like baikal [sogosync](https://github.com/xbgmsharp/sogosync), but really i'm fustrate with this. All the scripts api gives a different error to setup with sogo server.

I have trying to configure sogo server to my local server using php, i have try with sabredav package and follow the installation guide.

https://sabre.io/dav/

Finally i have also try with  CardDav-PHP library but i don't know he is giving a response code 200 but i have got response like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2013 14:12:12 GMT
content-length: 2595
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
set-cookie: 0xHIGHFLYxSOGo=discard; expires=Fri, 25-Oct-2013 14:12:12 GMT; path=/SOGo/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close*  
We've detected that your browser version is currently not supported on this site. Our    recommendation is to use Firefox. Click on the link below to download the most current version of this
```

I don't know why this happen on simple api call:

```
require_once 'carddav.php';
$carddav = new carddav_backend('https://mysogourl/SOGo/mysogousername/Contacts/');
$carddav->set_auth('mysogousername', 'mysogopassword');
$obj = $carddav->get();
echo "<pre>";print_r($obj);exit;
```

Any tutorial or example would be great.

Comment: Maybe my detailed tutorial can help you in any way: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/05/owncloud-mit-thunderbird-und-android-verbinden-komplettanleitung/